# Looping ruby hash and output specific element

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

I am trying to loop through a hash for specific data to output. If I want to output all usernames. This is how I can do it one at a time but its not what I want.

```
puts username = json["users"][0]["username"]
puts username = json["users"][1]["username"]
```

also tried

```
json.each { |x| puts json["users"][x]["username"]}
```

This is the hash structure

```
{"success"=>true, "users"=>[{"id"=>"1523493", "username"=>"myname","age"=>"21"},{"id"=>"653172", "username"=>"anothername","age"=>"65"}]}
```

sorry I didnt make my question clear enough. I am wanting to iterate the hash for "username" and then i can loop through each username and output specific data before moving to next username

Comment: also users.map { |entry| puts entry["usersname"]} gives me an error no implicit conversion of String into Integer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop your json like this

```
json["users"].each do |u|
   username = u["username"]
   #Do some logic with username
   #like user = User.find_by_username(username)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all the usernames in one go by doing something like this:

```
json = { "users" => [{"id"=>"1523493", "username"=>"myname"},{"id"=>"653172", "username"=>"anothername"}] }

json["users"].map { |user| user["username"] }
# => ["username", "anothername"]
```

The above will provide you with an array of usernames to do with as you see fit. :)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Sorry I didnt make my question clear enough I think. For each occurrence of "username" I would like to use it as the loop so I then can extract the elements I need. also I didnt post the proper hash and have now corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

```
h = {"success"=>true, 
     "users"=>[{"id"=>"1523493", "username"=>"myname","age"=>"21"},
               {"id"=>"653172", "username"=>"anothername","age"=>"65"}]}

h["users"].map { |user| user["username"] }
   #=> ["myname", "anothername"]
```

Comment: that does work great but, I have updated my quest because I wasnt clear enough and i posted the wrong hash structure, sorry.